# How to group in javascript and detect if exist one

Tags: javascript

I would like to detect for each day if a specific code is present in this input:

```
const arrayA = [
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"C"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"C"}];
```

Rule : if B is present for the day then we add X
if C is present for the day then we add Y
if B & C are present for the day we add Y

I lost my self in my code with filter and .some as you can see...

Expected output

```
   const arrayOut = [
    {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
    {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
    {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"C"},
    {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
    {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"Y"},
    {"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"A"},
    {"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
    {"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"X"}];
```

```js
const arrayA = [
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"C"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"}];

var helper = [];
arrayA.map ( e => {
  var key = e.date;
  if(!helper[key]){
     helper.push(key);
     var arr = arrayA.filter(e => e.date == key && (e.code == "B" || e.code == "C"));

      if(arr.length > 0) console.log("act is here");
      else console.log("act not here");
 }
  
  });
```

Comment: Are your dates always sorted?

Comment: Preprocessing the data would be easier.

Comment: No it is not always sorted what do you mean by preprocessing ? Thank you

Comment: If it's not always sorted, does it matter where the new `X` and `Y` objects are inserted? Also, in your expected output you have added an `X` for `2018/9/11` but no `B` is present. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to first create a map between dates and the set of codes related to they. After this task is done, you can loop on the map and depending on the set of codes a `date` have associated with it insert the new elements on the original `arrayA`:

```js
const arrayA = [
  {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
  {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
  {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"C"},
  {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
  {"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
  {"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"}
];

// Create map between dates and set of codes they have.

let dateMap = arrayA.reduce((map, {date, code}) =>
{
    if (map.has(date))
        map.set(date, map.get(date).add(code));
    else
        map.set(date, new Set(code));

    return map;
}, new Map());

// Now, loop on the map to check what elements to add.

dateMap.forEach((codes, date) =>
{
    if (codes.has("C") && codes.has("B"))
        arrayA.push({date, code: "Y"});
    else if (codes.has("C"))
        arrayA.push({date, code: "Y"});
    else if (codes.has("B"))
        arrayA.push({date, code: "X"});
});

console.log("Unsorted: ", arrayA);

// Now, if you need, you can sort the array.

arrayA.sort(
    (a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date) || a.code.localeCompare(b.code)
);

console.log("Sorted: ", arrayA);
```

Comment: Im so sad, I have the error "Map" is not defined. I guess I can't use your solution

Comment: @Louis In what environment / browser are you running the code? Check [browser-compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: I am using it in an environment of a software where i cannot do really much... I tried the below solution with Object.entries but it also doesn't exist... 'Cannot find function entries in object function Object()' How could i do without entries and map ?

Comment: @Louis Use **epascarello** answer, but for iterate on objects use [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) instead of `Object.entries()`. Example: `for (let date in state) { if (state[date].C) arrayA.push({ date, code: 'Y' }) else if (state[date].B) arrayA.push({ date, code: 'X' }) }`

Comment: @Louis I have updated **epascarello's**  answer to show how to do it without `Object.entries()`.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would map it to an object so you can do an easy boolean check and than just append the item to the list.

```js
const arrayA = [
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"C"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"}];

const state = arrayA.reduce( (obj, state) => {
  obj[state.date] = obj[state.date] || {}
  obj[state.date][state.code] = true
  return obj
}, {});

Object.entries(state).forEach(([date, codes]) => {
  if (codes.C) {
    arrayA.push({ date, code: 'Y' })
  } else if (codes.B) {
    arrayA.push({ date, code: 'X' })
  }
})

console.log(arrayA)
```

---

## Update to approach the same Without `Object.entries()`:

```js
const arrayA = [
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"C"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"}];

const state = arrayA.reduce( (obj, state) => {
  obj[state.date] = obj[state.date] || {}
  obj[state.date][state.code] = true
  return obj
}, {});

for (date in state)
{
  if (state[date].C)
    arrayA.push({ date, code: 'Y' });
  else if (state[date].B)
    arrayA.push({ date, code: 'X' });
}

console.log(arrayA);
```

Comment: I have updated your answer to give the OP an alternative of how to implement this without `Object.entries()`. I hope this don't disturb you...

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the data in a map and check later for the wanted code.

```js
const
    array = [{ date: "2018/9/10", code: "A"}, { date: "2018/9/10", code: "B" }, { date: "2018/9/10", code: "C" }, { date: "2018/9/10", code: "A" }, { date: "2018/9/11", code: "A" }, { date: "2018/9/11", code: "B" }],
    result = Array
        .from(array.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.date, [...(m.get(o.date) || []), o]), new Map).values())
        .reduce((r, a) => {
            var code;
            if (a.some(({ code }) => code === 'B')) code = 'X';
            if (a.some(({ code }) => code === 'C')) code = 'Y';
            if (code) a.push({ date: a[0].date, code });
            return r.concat(a);
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```